# PHP $_SESSION empty value

Tags: php, session

I want to display `$new_client` variable in `preview.php` but I get no value there, if I set any other variable to `klmn` session then it works fine. What is wrong?

`pdf/index.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    header('location:../error.php');
    exit;
};

include("add_client.php");
$_SESSION['klnm']=$new_client;
echo $_SESSION['klnm'];
```

`pdf/add_client.php`

```
<?php


if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    header('location:../error.php');
    exit;
};
require("../config.php");


$new_client = strtolower($_POST['new-offer']);

$_SESSION['klnm']=$new_client;
```

`pdf/preview.php`

```
<?php
session_start();

$klient = $_SESSION['klnm'];
echo $_SESSION['klnm'];
```

my form kokpit/index.php

```
<form method="post" action="../PDF/index.php">
                    <input type="text" name="new-offer">
                    <button type="submit">Wygeneruj</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$_POST['new-offer']`, have you made a POST request to `index.php`?

Comment: Can you show us your form ?

Comment: It displays fine in index but it's broken in preview.php I don't understand why

Comment: Is the session started successfully, what is the return value of `session_start()` in both pages?

Comment: @jeroen how to check it? Sorry I'm pretty new

Comment: `$result = session_start(); var_dump($result);` as the first 2 lines in your pages.

Comment: yep I get bool(true) in both.

Comment: Do you get the same `session_id()` in both pages?

Comment: I don't think it's session_id issue, because if I pass anything else to session klmn then it works fine, it must be something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a `<button 'type'=submit 'name'=submit`..> to test for isset($_POST['submit']) to wait for user input... It's also helpful to test if session is already started(see code below) to avoid notices / unforeseen behaviour:

index.php:

```
 <?php
    session_start();

    echo 'in INDEX' . '<br />';

    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
        header('location:../error.php');
        exit;
    };

    include("add_client.php");

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $_SESSION['klnm']=$new_client;
    echo '<br />' . 'INDEX output - $SESSION[klnm]: ' . $_SESSION['klnm'];

    echo "<br /> <br /> <a href='preview.php' > go preview </a>";
    }

    ?>

<form method="post" action="index.php">
        <input type="text" name="new-offer">
        <button type="submit" name='submit' >Wygeneruj</button>
        </form>
```

add_client.php:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    header('location:../error.php');
    exit;
};

//require("../config.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
echo '<br />' . 'in ADD_CLIENT, adding the client ' . '<br />';

$new_client = strtolower($_POST['new-offer']);

$_SESSION['klnm']=$new_client;
}
```

preview.php:

```
<?php
// check if session already started
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
    session_start();
}

echo '<br />' . 'in PREVIEW' . '<br />';

$klient = $_SESSION['klnm'];
echo '$SESSION[klnm] == ' . $_SESSION['klnm'];

echo "<br /> <br /> <a href='index.php' > back to index </a>";
?>
```

Comment: As far as I know session_start should be at the top of document, so moving form there isn't good move I guess. Also how addding name to submit button could help me in my case? I can display form input in add_client, but it doesn't work in preview. Also I can set for example $_SESSION['klnm']='some_test' in add_client and it will display just fine in preview.php, I have only problem with index.php form value sending via session

Comment: correct, the first statement should be session_start(); (edited), but for the rest of your problem - the reason you cannot see a value in preview.php, is because you don't pick it up with your your form submission in index, as explained.